# Any other solution for recursive solution

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was trying to find how many numbers of length n are there such that each number is at least 4 smaller/greater than the number before and after it. 
Eg: if n = 5, such numbers are 39518, 15951, etc.

Below is the solution, i could come up with:
It is taking a long amount of time even for input size as low as 1000.I am sure, there are some better approaches to solve this problem. I would appreciate if someone can give some pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int out[100000];
int count;
void foo(int *out, int pos_to_fil, int size) {
    if (pos_to_fil == size) {
        count++;
        return;
    }
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=9;i++) {
        if (pos_to_fil == 0 && i == 0)
            continue;
        if (pos_to_fil >0 && abs(out[pos_to_fil-1] -i) < 4)
            continue;
        out[pos_to_fil] = i;
        foo(out, pos_to_fil + 1, size);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    foo(out, 0, 1000);
    printf("count %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I may be interpreting it wrong  but isn't 39518 (+6)(-4)(-4)(+7) ?

Comment: the difference between each number should be **at least** 4 (in absolute), If I get it right @DennisCallanan

Comment: *[...] even for input size as low as 1000.* That means that you're trying to process numbers with a thousand digits right? Isn't that ten trecendotrigintillion possible values?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen is right, for 1000 input is it not posible to calculate it, I cant find what large is ten trecendotrigintillion, what is x in 10^x.

Comment: @maskacovnik It's 10^1000.

Comment: Ok, Even if you have this time @nomanpouight, you dont have as large stack as you need, but I guess it will me lower than 10^1000, but not enught to make it work

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen : there are not that much value. Each new digit allows an average 4.2 possibilities. 4^1000 is *only* ~ 10^600. But I'm afraid it is still far beyond the capacity of a single int variable and even a long long int ! (A majorand would be 5^1000 ~ 10^700)

Comment: you should use an iterative attempt, otherwise you will get trouble with stack-overflows ;-) the recursive stack is not too big...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: don't use recursion, go bottom up and use dynamic programming.

Longer answer:
Basically you're iterating over all possible solutions. The only statement that increases count is the `count++` and because we have to go up to a number with over 600 digits that's going to take a while. (Even if it wouldn't take a function call for every `count++`)

So somehow we need to increase count with a whole lot more then just 1 at the time. How to do that?

Suppose we already know the answer to n=2 is 36 possibilities. Does that help us to compute how many possibilities there are for n=3? No. Not really, because we don't know what those 36 numbers are. One of those two-digit numbers is `15` which could be extended to `150`, `151` and `159` (3 possibilities). Another two-digit number is `30` which could be extended to `304`, `305`, `306`, `307`, `308` and `309` (6 possibilities). We clearly can't just multiply 36 with some constant factor to arrive at the solution for n=3.

But there is a pattern nonetheless. The fact that `30` spawns 6 new numbers for the next generation implies that `40`, `50`, `60` and all other two-digit numbers that end on a `0` will also spawn 6 new numbers. `15` spawns 3 new numbers, and so will all other numbers that end on a `5`.

So what if we do start by computing n=2, and in stead of remembering all 36 numbers, we remember this array: `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. This array implies we don't know exactly what those 36 numbers are, but 6 of them end on a `0`, 5 of them end on a `1`, 4 on a `2` and so on.

Now we can compute the same array for n=3 by doing some additions. `0` can be spawned from a `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` or `9`. Adding them all up implies that for n=3 there will be 2 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 18 numbers that end on a `0`. The entire array for n=3 is `[18, 16, 14, 12, 15, 16, 15, 18, 20, 22]`

Unfortunately I don't speak c but here is a solution in java.

```
import java.util.*;                                                         
import java.math.*;                                                         

class BigNum {                                                              


    public static void main (String[] a) {                                  
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);                               
        System.out.println (new BigNum().solve(in.nextInt()));              
    }                                                                       


    BigInteger solve(int n) {                                               
        if (n == 0) return BigInteger.ZERO;                                 
        BigInteger[] counts = new BigInteger[10];                           
        BigInteger[] next = new BigInteger[10];                             
        BigInteger[] temp;                                                  
        Arrays.fill (counts, BigInteger.ONE);                               
        counts[0] = BigInteger.ZERO;                                        

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {                                       
            for (int nextDigit = 0; nextDigit < 10; nextDigit++) {          
                next[nextDigit] = BigInteger.ZERO;                          
                for (int digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++) {                  
                    if (Math.abs (digit - nextDigit) >= 4) {                
                        next[nextDigit] = next[nextDigit].add (counts[digit]);
                    }                                                       
                }                                                           
            }                                                               
            temp = counts;                                                  
            counts = next;                                                  
            next = temp;                                                    
        }                                                                   

        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;                                   
        for (BigInteger i : counts) sum = sum.add  (i);                     
        return sum;                                                         
    }                                                                       

}
```

It has two arrays: `counts` for the array of the current generation (n=2 in the example above) and `next` for the next generation (n=3 in the example). When the algorithm is done computing `next` it swaps the two arrays, implying we'll use the `next` from this generation as a current for the next generation.

It has 3 for loops. The outer loop simply counts generations and isn't used at all. The `nextDigit` counts the digits in the next generation, while `digit` counts the digit in the current generation. When they're at least 4 apart we do the addition.

And in case you're wondering, the result for n=1000 is indeed quite big, and took me 165 milliseconds to compute:

58671138329570171371420484902268532315073277852051653969830525802838628724212731137694290047005040297045274423072752812252866695216074181116219893270512906481125049825987756071510466880415373048496191391932743103313044071304405218219902707133109687674960299002863298632965964118240544824530569540542700793488917467060307664191744432111922492168260259079355618958225678548171234101375097873342091776899282686824362584042717489292059166512255400959907373002265039739675037774831081921743873154470907306563401667845616259033848968890244196752759640923743592116170624821165172596009768024780906078208584276112384909371479169927564723938874400811048288 possibilities.

Comment: i really don't see where you are reusing the n=2 to calculate n=3? I see your logic as this which may be wrong as i don't understand java much.
Let's calculate for n=3. So all you are doing is doing brute force.
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 26, 27, 28, 29.... and so on. With this in place you add one more element 159, 160, 170, 180, .......
One 'for' loop for first digit from 1 to 9. Second 'for' loop for second digit and third 'for' loop for checking all the possibilities. Even though i have marked it as correct can you add some comments around the code?

Comment: ok I edited the text and added some explanation. Also I should thank you for making me look at it again, because there was a silly bug in my code (swapping of the arrays is needed, can't just assign)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can rewrite the for header to make it shorter using two for cycles:

```
int previous = out[pos_to_fill-1];
int i;
//lower than 4
for (i=0;i<previous-4;i++) {
    //... for cycle body
}
//higher than 4
for (i=previous+4;i<=9;i++) {
    //... for cycle body (the same)
}
```

To not repeat cycle body, I would put body to function if it wont have many parameters

Note: not tested, starting `i` values and conditions can be bad, this is only an idea